# JSON add nested sub objects dynamically using JS or JQuery

Tags: json, local-storage, key-value

I am creating a services cart at client side
where services are grouped inside 3 level of groupings like

```
product[SECTION] [SERVICE]   [ITEM]
product['carpet']['cleaning']['room']   = {'qty':2,'price':15};
product['carpet']['cleaning']['hall']   = {'qty':1,'price':10};
product['carpet']['protecting']['hall'] = {'qty':1,'price':10}; 
product['carpet']['deodorize']['hall']  = {'qty':1,'price':10};
product['leather']['cleaning']['sofa']  = {'qty':1,'price':10};
```

want to generate above structure of json.

my text boxes looks like below notice `data-section` `data-service` `data-tem`  and `data-price`

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-number" 
       data-price="15" data-section="carpet" data-item="room" data-service="protect" />
```

My JS code is as below, but it adds only current item while overwriting all other services and sections.

```
$(function(){
    $('.input-number').change(function(){
        var section = $(this).attr('data-section');
        var item = $(this).attr('data-item');
        var service = $(this).attr('data-service');
        var qty = $(this).val();
        var unitprice = $(this).attr('data-unitprice'); 

        addProduct(section,item,service,qty,unitprice);
    });
});

function addProduct(section,item,service,qty,unitprice){
    let products = {};
    if(localStorage.getItem('products')){
        products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products'));
    }

    products['"'+section+'"'] =
    { 
        ['"'+service+'"'] : {
            ['"'+item+'"'] : {
                'unitprice' : unitprice, 'qty': qty
            }
        } 
    }; 
    
    localStorage.setItem('products', JSON.stringify(products));
}
```

How can I append only instead of overwriting  nested items?

*****EDITED*****
I have edited my add product function as below but still not getting desired result

```
function addProduct(section,item,service,qty,unitprice){
    let products = {};
    if(localStorage.getItem('products')){
        products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products'));
    }
    

    var v = {
        [service] : {
            [item] :{
                "qty":qty,'unitprice':unitprice
            }
        }
    };

    products.push( section, v );

             
    localStorage.setItem('products', JSON.stringify(products));
}

Object.prototype.push = function( key, value ){
    if(typeof value === 'object'){ 
        var k = Object.keys(value)[0];
        value.push( k, value[k] );
    }
    this[ key ] = value;
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all that is not a good way to store your data.

Here's a better way to store your data.
It's much more easy to understand if you see it like an object cause in javascript it's the same thing

```
//example this 2 data is store the same way in javascript
var product['carpet']['cleaning']['room']   = {'qty':2,'price':15};

var product = [{
  carpet: {
    cleaning: {
      room: {'qty':2,'price':15}
    }
  }
}]

// my solution would be just save section, service and item in the object, example:
var product = [];
var v = {
  section: 'carpet',
  service: 'cleaning',
  item: 'room'
  qty:2,
  price:15
}
product.push(v)
```